# LSF ERROR:Project must be 'acc_*'

Tags: bash, shell, lsf

I need to run a Python script on a supercomputer by submitting a job with LSF. I have been trying to become acquainted with the syntax using a simple example script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#BSUB –q alloc
#BSUB –n 1
#BSUB –o t.out
echo “Salve Munde!”
```

I saved this file as example.txt, and on the command line, I ran:

```
$ bsub < example.txt
```

This returned the message:

```
LSF ERROR:Project must be 'acc_*'. Request aborted by esub. Job not submitted.
```

What is the cause of this error?

Comment: Try replacing "smart" quotes in `echo “Salve Munde!” ` with dumb (plain) quotes.

Comment: Do you see the same error if doing
bsub -q alloc -n 1 -o t.out echo "Slave Munde!"? From the error message it seems you have an esub program to check job submission option.